# TYPO3 - Fluid Translate in PHP ViewHelper within extension

Tags: typo3, typo3-8.x, typo3-extensions

Using PHP 8.7.17

I have the following viewhelper to give an example of what I require

```
<?php namespace SRS\SrsPccLog\ViewHelpers;
  use TYPO3\CMS\Fluid\Core\ViewHelper\AbstractViewHelper;

  class ShowDateAsStringViewHelper extends AbstractViewHelper
  {
      public function initializeArguments()
      {
           $this->registerArgument('month', 'integer', 'month value', true);
      }

       public function render()
       {
            $month = $this->arguments['month'];
            return $this->monthAsString($month, $year);
       }

       public function monthAsString ($month) {
          switch ($month) {
            case 1:
                 return "January";
            case 2:
                 return "February";
            case 3:
                 return "March";
            case 4:
                 return "April";
            case 5:
                 return "May";
            default:
                 return "";
         }
   }
```

I have the function but what I simply want to do is display the month in the native language, ie replace `return "January'`

with `<f:translate key="tx_srspcclog_domain_model_myext.january" />`

so that I can be less language specific and get the language from the language files like i do for a fluid view. Any ideas of how to do this when you not in a fluid view but a PHP view helper

Comment: The FormatDate ViewHelper understands format strings in strftime(). You don't need to localize anything yourself at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\LocalizationUtility::translate($key, $extensionName)
```

Comment: this method worked for me, awesome !! Thanks for the heads up :)

Answer (score 0):

Look inside the TranslateViewHelper and see how they did it (most likely the `translate(...)` method), and use the code to render your own labels from your XLFF files

Answer (score 0):

What you are actually looking for is "%B".

As the documentation clearly states, the FormatDate ViewHelper understands format strings in strftime() as well as date() format. strftime already has localization built in. You don't need to translate anything yourself.

https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/ExtbaseGuide/Fluid/ViewHelper/Format/Date.html#localized-time-using-strftime-syntax
http://php.net/manual/de/function.strftime.php

Comment: so does typo 3 have localisation for welsh dates ?

Comment: @AndrewPrice I realize now that my answer was somewhat oblivious. I've never tested it myself, but setLocale at least states that Welsh is supported. The two letter language code would be "CY". See http://php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale.php and https://www.w3.org/WAI/ER/IG/ert/iso639.htm .